# How can I generate a kernel dump using WMI/WinRM?

Tags: c#, wmi

I want to generate a kernel dump using WinRM or WMI. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate OS Forcedump(Minidump)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929396/generate-os-forcedumpminidump)

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134048/generating-net-crash-dumps-automatically).

Comment: @Cody Gray - exact duplicate, even down to the OP... given the duplicate suggestion, I guess we both flagged ;)